# How to convert not HTML 4 entities to be shown?

Tags: javascript, python, html, entities

I have some entities that are not [standard ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) like `&scedil;` or `&ccaron;`

Is there a way to convert these entities to the UTF-8 characters (`č` and `ş` in my example) or to something else that can be shown in a html page?

I would like to do it in javascript, but if it is not possible I can pre-process the content server-side in python.

thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Turkish_characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to do a regex search and replace of these entities over the body of the document. Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">

window.onload = function(){
    var entities = [{entity:"scedil", char:"č"},
                    {entity:"ccaron", char:"ş"}]; // array of entities to replace

    for (var i in entities){
        var regex = new RegExp("(\&amp;|\&)"+entities[i].entity+";", "ig");
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(regex, entities[i].char);
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
These entities will be replaced: &scedil; and &ccaron;
</body>
```

It would be better however to replace the characters with proper HTML entities. These will be shown properly on all standard browsers. For example:

```
...
var entities = [{entity:"scedil", char:"&#269;"},
                {entity:"ccaron", char:"&#351;"}]; // array of entities to replace
...
```

However, in my opinion it would be better to do this on the server-side and not in JavaScript. In that case, a server-side script would do effectively the same as above but before the client received the text rather than the client doing it afterwards. Doing it on the server side would avoid a the text being visibly "fixed" after the page had loaded.

Comment: I was thinking to the same solution, but, if possible, I would like to avoid to define a mapping of entities and UTF-8 characters in my code! I would like to use some standard functions either in javascript (but it seems clear to me that there is nothing around) or in Python.

Comment: Hi I also found the problem , I have tones of &scedil; or &ccaron; or &acaron;and so many things. How should I solve it ? I found those in my XML file. Pls help me. In my DTD, I don't see that those entity are defined.